# Testing for component/props is undefined with Enzyme in ReactJS

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test if the LoginContainer component via props exists in the Header with Enzyme, but I'm not having luck.

Here's my main app:

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import LoginContainer from './LoginContainer'

const App = () => (
    <Header login={<LoginContainer />} />
)
export default App
```

My Header:

```
import React from "react";
const Header = ({login}) =>
    <header role="banner">
        {login}
    </header>
export default Header
```

And this is my Test:

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Header from '../components/Header'

const setup = props => {
    const component = shallow(
        <Header {...props} />
    )
    return {
        component: component
    }
}
describe('Header component', () => {
    it('should render login', () => {
        const { component } = setup();
        console.log(component.props({ login })) //this is undefined
    })
})
```

The problem is when I run the test it seems that login(LoginContainer) props is undefined. Can someone advice please?

Comment: where do you call setup? I dont see any call.

Comment: sorry, forgot to add. I've just updated.

Comment: You are not passing anything to `setup`

Answer (score 3):

You should get the instance first.

> NOTE: When called on a shallow wrapper, .props() will return values for props on the root node that the component renders, not the component itself. To return the props for the entire React component, use wrapper.instance().props. See .instance() => ReactComponent

e.g.

```
            it('should have props', () => {                
                const l = <div>Login ...</div>;
                const {component} = setup({login:l});
                console.log(component.instance().props.login);
                expect(component.instance().props.login).to.exist;
            });
```

Comment: The above gives an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'exist' of undefined. :(

Comment: That's because I'm using Chai for the example. If you are not using Chai, you should use another expectation, like `to.have.length` or `to.equal` depending of what you expect.

Comment: I know. I've tried everything `to.have.length`,`to.equal`,`.to.equal(true)`, `toBe(1)` but none of them worked. Always getting `undefined`. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing anything to setup.

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Header from '../components/Header'

const setup = props => {
    const component = shallow(
        <Header {...props} />
    )
    return {
        component: component
    }
}
describe('Header component', () => {
    it('should render login', () => {
        const { component } = setup({ login: <LoginContainer/> });
        expect(component.props().login).toBeDefined()
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for advice, but your solution still shows undefined or Expected value to be defined, instead received "undefined"